# Как сделать адаптивную высоту ячейки в таблице

Tags: html, css

Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает height?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td {
  height: 100%;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  height: 40px;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TOP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CENTER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BOTTOM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: По-моему всё работает. Высота ячейки адаптируется под контент, содержащийся в ней. (при height:100%)

Comment: @Denis I Почему то игнорируется высота `height 400px;` и должна 1 строка адаптироваться под всю высоту относительно этих 400px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё бы работало хорошо, если не торопиться, быть чуть внимательнее. Просто забыли двоеточие.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) td {
  height: 100%;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  height: 40px;
}

table tr:nth-child(3) td {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>TOP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CENTER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BOTTOM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: +, А еще лучше пользоваться инструментами с подсветкой синтаксиса и ошибок

Comment: @DenisI: согласен. Любая "песочница" в помощь :)